# How to fetch and display just the count of grep matches against each file that has the matching string?

Tags: bash, list, count, scripting, grep

```
cat Samplescript
```

```
for OUTPUT in $(grep -lR "Sample sv15 Processor" ./*) #List files with matching string
do
    grep "Sample sv15 Processor" $OUTPUT | wc -l
done
```

My approach is to list files with matching strings
Then run a grep search against each file name from the list.
Finally, use `wc -l` via pipeline

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried using
###
for OUTPUT in $(grep -lR "Sample sv15 Processor" ./*)
do
    grep -c "Sample sv15 Processor" $OUTPUT
done
###
as well

Comment: IIUC what you need it just `grep -cR ./* | grep -v ':0$'`. If that's not what you're looking for, please edit your question with example input and example output you're expecting.

Comment: I am to debug a versioning issue in my application. I have a log directory that has multiple log files [log rotated]. Among those 20 files, I need to know which files have "Sample sv15 Processor" strings and the count of occurrence for each of those matching files. Your comment gave me some clue and I was able to get it done just via grep -cR 'stringtomatch' ./* . Thanks @root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by @root in the comments `grep -cR 'stringtomatch' ./*` will do the task.